# How to copy a model instance to another model based on attribute value in Django

Tags: python, django, model, copy, instance

I want to copy a model instance from my Tasks class into my CompletedTasks class if and only if the progress attribute in my Tasks object is set to "completed".  The I want to delete the object from the Tasks class.  How do i set it up to automatically do this when a user edits a task and inputs completed for progress

I tried a few different methods, but I am not exactly sure how to go about this.  The function completedTasks(self,id) below is what I currently have, but it doesn't do anything.

I also have a create and update task functions in my views.py, would it make sense to put the desired functionality there instead of in models.py?

```
class Progress(models.Model):
    level =  models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Tasks(models.Model):
    progress = models.ForeignKey(Progress, max_length=20, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def  completedTasks(self, id):
    instance = Tasks.objects.get(pk = id)

    if(instance.progress == "completed"):
        temp = CompletedTasks()
        temp = instance 
        temp.save()
        instance.delete()

class CompletedTasks(Tasks):
```

Comment: use post save signal handler for Task class.

Comment: great detailed answer, tell it again.

Comment: Someone soon will write a short answer for you.

Comment: You say the progress attribute needs to set to completed, but progress is a foreign key to a Progress class. Should this be a char field?

Answer (score 0):

Your view can be like this

```
def  completedTasks(self, id):
    instance = Tasks.objects.get(pk = id)

    if(instance.progress == "completed"):
        temp = CompletedTasks(**instance.__dict__)
        temp.id = None # to force adding new record
        temp.save()
        instance.delete()
```

But in design terms, you don’t need to move Task to completeTask, filtering based on status is enough.

Comment: will try this, but for now it keeps telling me that I need an instance from the Progress class instead of "completed".  What is the proper syntax for that?

Comment: Which line tells you that?